# скрыть содержимое атрибута js

Tags: javascript, html

Есть код вставки видео с рутуба

Нужно придумать как скрыть путь к видео из исходного кода. Работать должно не только для рутуба, но и для любого сайта, который указан во фрейме.

Comment: Отличное тз! Только ответ - путь не скрыть, но если придумаешь обязательно напиши как)

Answer (score 1):

Это не возможно, дебаггер того же хрома все равно покажет путь, по которому загружен ресурс. Как бы вы не прятали/обфусцировали/шифровали его в коде, в конечном итоге это все равно превратиться в обычный сетевой запрос с конечным `url`

Чего именно вы хотите добиться этим способом?